# Dual monitor setup issue, 2nd monitor constantly goes black 1-2 seconds ever so often when I use an application that uses a microphone (ex. Discord)

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers, multiple-monitors, microphone

I currently use an Asus TUF FX504GE and want to have a double monitor setup using this new monitor I bought (Viewsonic VA2432) however, my monitor constantly goes black for 1-2 seconds whenever I use an application that uses a microphone like discord or whenever I'm on a zoom meeting for my online classes. I've exhausted all possible solutions I could find on the internet so any help would be much appreciated. When I'm not using any app that uses a microphone, the 2nd monitor seems to never give a black screen so I suspect there's something wrong with my microphone drivers. I tried updating it on the device manager, uninstalling it, and even installing the new drivers provided by realtek.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have problem with Driver or Power.
Try to use SoundCard on USB.

Comment: Please share yours finall story which solve yours issue. Power or driver?  What you change?

Comment: I bought a USB soundcard as you suggested and I've been using it for a week now and so far, the 2nd monitor stopped giving a black screen. Thank you so much for the suggestion although I don't know what exactly caused the problem for my 2nd monitor whenever I use an application that uses a microphone.

Comment: `I don't know what exactly caused the problem` my crystal ball says `power management` on your mother board.